# is there a way I can instantiate a button and then attach a function to it from some other list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an interaction system for a TPS game and am currently trying to make a Splinter Cell-like interaction system where you can choose what you're going to interact with in a pop-up menu.

[image]

I figured out a way to create the list of interactables and get an UI set up, but I don't know how to assign the interaction of the specific items (which have an interface for interacting with an empty Interact function) to a click of the button.

I am guessing events is the way to go, but I don't know how to assign the script to the button onClicked event by instantiating it.

[image]

[image]

`

```
private void Update()
    {
        interactorsFound = Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc(interactor.position, GetComponent<BoxCollider>().size, collidersFound, Quaternion.identity, interactablesLayer, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);

        if (interactorsFound != 0)
        {
            interactionUI.SetActive(true);
            interactionInteractButton.SetActive(true);

            for (int i = 0; i < interactorsFound; i++)
            {
                var _interactorsFound = collidersFound[i];
                if (_interactorsFound.GetComponent<IInteract>() != null)
                {
                    if (!interactablesList.Contains(_interactorsFound.gameObject))
                    {
                        interactablesList.Add(_interactorsFound.gameObject);
                        foreach (GameObject item in interactablesList)
                        {
                            if (interactionBackground.transform.childCount > 0)
                            {
                                for (int k = 0; k < interactionBackground.transform.childCount; k++)
                                {
                                    Destroy(interactionBackground.transform.GetChild(k).gameObject);
                                }
                            }
                            StartCoroutine(DeleteRoutine(interactionBackground));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // if interactorsFound == 0
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < interactionBackground.transform.childCount; i++)
            {
                Destroy(interactionBackground.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
            }
            interactablesList.Clear();
            interactionUI.SetActive(false);
            interactionInteractButton.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DeleteRoutine(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => gameObject.transform.childCount == 0);

        for (int j = 0; j < interactablesList.Count; j++)
        {
            Instantiate(interactionOption, interactionUI.transform.position, quaternion.identity, interactionBackground.transform);
            interactionBackground.transform.GetChild(j).GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().text = interactablesList[j].name;
            interactionBackground.transform.GetChild(j).name = interactablesList[j].name;
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initiate Button**

You can initiate a button prefab or pre-existing game object with button component.

**Add Onclick Event Listener to it**

Use GetComponent() method to get the button component. Then use button.Onclick.AddListener(YourButtonClickMethod) to add the button-clicked  method you want.

You can get the code example from the link below (the onClick part) :
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Button.html

Comment: This is what i did just a few moments ago and then checked here for a reply. And yes, it worked. I don't understand why Unity calls this "deprecated"... Thanks.

Comment: @Madalin could you post the deprecate log?  Deprecate warning usually means there is better way to implement the code.

Comment: @Wiliard Peng Well for some reason that doesn't show up anymore, but if you go to the Unity Scripting documentation you will see Obsoloete, use Button.clicked instead. [Button.onClick](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Button-onClick.html) - and [here's](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Button-clicked.html) the link of the method Unity suggests you use instead.